# Write string with null bytes inside (PNG image) into MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How do I **write and read** string (~200 KB) with lots of 0 bytes inside into MySQL BLOB field?

This  is not working:

```
$data = ... // PNG image raw data
$queryPart = "'" . addslashes($data) . "'";
... compose and execute query
```

Comment: `addslashes()` is not a secure method for escaping data. You should be using the escape function provided in the `mysql` or `mysqli` library, or a cross-DB library like PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to escape input data when using the legacy MySQL library is mysql_real_escape_string().

Comment: Yes, this will fix the null byte issue, as well as the security hole currently in the OP's application.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, but I knew about this method and it also do not work for me :( I believe the problem is in AMFPHP that I use to deliver the data from client. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even if they "can", databases are not made to stock binary files. It's more efficient to have in your table the path of the files on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_real_escape_string(), as it makes a call to the MySQL library to clean the given data.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php